# solving the differential equation $y''− k^2y=0$; using reduction of order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a way to solve
$$y''−k^2(y)=0$$
using only the reduction of order method? I reduced it and continued with separation of variables, but the solution looks completely different from the solution given by the book
$$y=c_1 e^{kx} + c_2 e^{−kx}$$
my solution is: $x=\ln \left|\sqrt{k^2y^2+c_1}+ky\right| +c_2$
Is there any way to turn this equation into the one above?

Comment: Book's solution certainly looks correct, and yours looks substantially different, but hard to say where you made the mistake if you don't post the entire argument you used to come up with your solution...

Comment: I substituted y'=p, y''=p(dp/dy). I then have the equation p(dp/dy)=k^2y.

Comment: then I used separation of variables to get the equation p^2=y^2k^2+c1. substituting back and taking the square root, I have the equation dy/dx=sqrt(y^2k^2 +c1). again separating the variables and integrating, I get the solution I mentioned

Comment: oh the x on thr LHS should by multiplied by k, by still that is very different from the solution given by the book

Comment: Your solutions looks correct, look up the alternative forms of $Ar\sinh=\sinh^{-1}$. However, to get the general real solution in your form you will need complex-valued constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
y'' - k^{2}y = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow (y'' - ky') + (ky' - k^{2}y) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (y' - ky)' + k(y' - ky) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u' + ku = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u = ae^{-kx}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y' - ky = ae^{-kx}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (ye^{-kx})' = ae^{-2kx}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow ye^{-kx} = be^{-2kx} + c\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y(x) = be^{-kx} + ce^{kx}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: wow that's way better! thank you!

Comment: @AhmedSamir you are welcome! I am glad I could help.